# Saving special characters in SQLite

Tags: c#, sqlite

I have the following code in C #, and when I insert a special character like 'μ' in a TextBox, the data in the database in SQLite is saved as ï¼. How can I insert the 'μ' character in the TextBox and keep the same 'μ' character in the database?

**My code C#:**

```
SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand();

            cmd.Connection = new SQLiteConnection(_connectionString);
            cmd.Connection.Open();

            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Categoria (Id, Nome) VALUES(@id, @nome)";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@id", 0));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@nome", tbCategoria.Text));

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd.Connection.Close();
```

Comment: Neither C# nor SQLite will change any string. Why do you think it is saved as "ï¼"?

Comment: The result I see in my database after the insert is ï¼.

Comment: And what software are you using to "see"?

Comment: I'm using SQLite Administrator: 
http://sqliteadmin.orbmu2k.de/

Comment: What is the output of `SELECT hex(Nome) FROM Categoria WHERE Id = 123` for this record?

Comment: I have as result = CEBC

Comment: But when I ran the query in Visual studio select Name from Category Where Id = 5, μ got the result. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try SQLiteSpy (http://www.yunqa.de/delphi/doku.php/products/sqlitespy/index) instead, it displays UTF-8 correctly.